# Reduce margin around tcolorbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

How to go about getting the text to have minimal spacing to the outline of a `tcolorbox:`

[image]

I would like to know how to adjust this spacing shown in red.  Thank you!

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}

%%------------ AM: Double Sideband Large Carrier ---------------
\hspace*{0.07cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}

    \begin{mybox}{AM: Double Sideband Large Carrier [DSB-LC\text{]}}
\lipsum[2]

    \end{mybox}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to adjust the left margin with the `left=2pt` parameter and the right margin with the `right=2pt` parameter.

What produces:

[image: tcolorbox]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}

%%------------ AM: Double Sideband Large Carrier ---------------
\hspace*{0.07cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}

    \begin{mybox}{AM: Double Sideband Large Carrier [DSB-LC\text{]}}
\lipsum[2]

    \end{mybox}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `left` and `right`, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white, left=4pt, right=2pt}

%%------------ AM: Double Sideband Large Carrier ---------------
\hspace*{0.07cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}

    \begin{mybox}{AM: Double Sideband Large Carrier [DSB-LC\text{]}}
\lipsum[2]

    \end{mybox}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is Markdown format typo for the left and right option.

Comment: @jdhao: ??? I didn't use Markdown – it's all LaTeX code. What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: Hi, Bernard, I mean there are typos in the first sentence of your answer: you are missing a backtick. Unfortunately, stackexchange does not allow the change of only character. You have to fix it yourself.

Comment: @jdhao: Oh! yes – it seems I forgot to type the opening ` of `left`. Thank you for warning me!